# Access a VideoPlayer of another scene to use VideoPlayer.Prepare()

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-player, preserve

I'm learning Unity and I have to improve the transition between a sequence of scenes which each has a GameObject called VideoManager and each of those has a VideoPlayer. I have thought use VideoPlayer.Prepare() to pre-load the next VideoPlayer of the next scene but I have found that acces to GameObject from another scene It's realy hard.

I have been searching for possibles solutions and I'm currently trying one, let me explain.

1. Create a script `VPGlobalManager` with two attributes:

```
[SerializeField] public List<VideoPlayer> _secuence;
[SerializeField] public int _indexCurrentVP;
```

I want that the list `_secuence` continue through the life of the app, and the `_indexCurrentVP` is the pointer to which the current active scene can acces to know which video .Prepare() (in general for each scene I only want Prepare the next VideoPlayer of the next scene). Finally I'm thinking in append this script to a `GameObject` and use `DontDestroyOnLoad` like this post [https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110958/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-data-between-scenes](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) or use a `static class`with those two attributes.

2. Now, this is the big issue : I haven't found a method to fill the list `_sequence`, because I have to acces to a `GameObject` from a current scene to a scene that hasn't been loaded  in order to add a reference to the next `VideoPlayer` (which is in the next scene) and then `Prepare()` it. I don't know have to do this, I have searched for a way to do it but the big problem is that the VideoPlayers are in differents scenes and I can change that. I want to achieve something like have a script called `VPOptimized`  and add it to each VideoManager with the next content

```
public class VPOptimize : MonoBehaviour
{
    VPManager _vpManager;

    private void Awake()
    {
        var _vp = transform.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>() as VideoPlayer;
        if (_vp != null)
        {
            _vpManager.instance._secuence.Add(_vp); 
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, Awake method only triggers in the active scene, so I can add all the VideoPlayers to my list . And that's all, if any of you can give feedback or advice to improve my solution or maybe find another I will be grateful.

Nice day :)

**Help me Obi Wan Strange Kenobi, you are my only hope
**

Comment: What does **videoplayer** do? Does it manage the video playlist or start play one video? About **videoplayer** on the next scene is necessary to have information before loading the scene?

Comment: Each VideoPlayer only play one video. It's a virtual travel with 360° videos and each one has quality between 2k and 4k. My app need to be built for Android and thats why I thought in using Prepare(). And yes, at last with my solution I need information of the next VideoPlayer before loading the next scene.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. Unity does not support multi scene references (i.e. reference a gameobject and/or component of one scene in another) out of the box. What DontDestroyOnLoad does is make sure some scripts last the full lifetime of the application and are not lost during scene load/unload, but it's not gonna help you populate that list of videoplayer references beforehand.

The usual way is to load a scene and use sth like [FindObjectOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) or one of its variations to find a reference to a component in one of the currently loaded scenes and cache it.

The other way would be to put all videos in a ScriptableObject which is an asset and can be referenced in all scenes and when a scene is loaded, get the video to play from the ScriptableObject and Prepare it.

As mentioned [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html),

> Awake is called either when an active GameObject that contains the script is initialized when a Scene loads, or when a...

So you should be able to call Prepare on the video selected, provided you know how each scene can find the video to play from the ScriptableObject. Some good material for this can be found here:

1. [Game architecture with ScriptableObjects | Open Projects Devlog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLDgtRNK2VE)
2. [Unite Austin 2017 - Game Architecture with Scriptable Objects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3iHhE_Kk)